# PHP login hash password changing all time

Tags: php, hash

Hello guys i have some problems with hash tag for my password:
I have problem with logining because this hash always refreshing ..

And i have one more question is this secure login ?

Login:

```
$email = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['email']));
$password = create_hash($_POST['password']);
$ip_adresa = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
    $test = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'"));
    $password = validate_password($password, $test['password']);

    $kveri = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($kveri)) {
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($kveri);
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['userid'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
    $mesec = 24*60*60*31; // mesec dana

    $sesija = md5($user['email'] . $cpass);

    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        /* Set cookie to last 1 year */
        setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], time()+ $mesec);
        setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), time()+ $mesec);
    } else {
        /* Cookie expires when browser closes */
        setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], false);
        setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), false);
    }

    setcookie("userid", $user['userid'], time()+ $mesec);
    setcookie("email", $user['email'], time()+ $mesec);
    setcookie("sesija", $sesija, time() + $mesec);
    $_SESSION['ok'] = "Uspesno";
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ip='$ip_adresa',sesija='$sesija' WHERE userid='$_SESSION[userid]'");
    header("Location:/index.php");

    } else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Password or email are incorrect";
    header("Location:/index.php#sign-in");
    die();          
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Email or password are empty";
    header("Location:/index.php#sign-in");
    die();
}
```

functions i using for hash:

```
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

function create_hash($password)
{
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" . 
        base64_encode(pbkdf2(
            PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
            $password,
            $salt,
            PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
            PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE,
            true
        ));
}

function validate_password($password, $correct_hash)
{
    $params = explode(":", $correct_hash);
    if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
       return false; 
    $pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
    return slow_equals(
        $pbkdf2,
        pbkdf2(
            $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
            $password,
            $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
            (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
            strlen($pbkdf2),
            true
        )
    );
}

// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
    $diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
    {
        $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
    }
    return $diff === 0; 
}

/*
 * PBKDF2 key derivation function as defined by RSA's PKCS #5: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt
 * $algorithm - The hash algorithm to use. Recommended: SHA256
 * $password - The password.
 * $salt - A salt that is unique to the password.
 * $count - Iteration count. Higher is better, but slower. Recommended: At least 1000.
 * $key_length - The length of the derived key in bytes.
 * $raw_output - If true, the key is returned in raw binary format. Hex encoded otherwise.
 * Returns: A $key_length-byte key derived from the password and salt.
 *
 * Test vectors can be found here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt
 *
 * This implementation of PBKDF2 was originally created by https://defuse.ca
 * With improvements by http://www.variations-of-shadow.com
 */
function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
        trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
        trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);

    if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
        // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
        if (!$raw_output) {
            $key_length = $key_length * 2;
        }
        return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
    }

    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
        // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
        // first iteration
        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
        // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
        $output .= $xorsum;
    }

    if($raw_output)
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    else
        return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
```

Comment: you're open to sql injection; use a prepared statement

Comment: What do you mean by "with hash tag for my password"? As said by Fred, you are vulnerable to sqlinjection. Also pbkdf2 function seems like your attempt to create an encription function. You should ALWAYS use built in encrypt functions in the language, as they will be much more secure than your own implementation.

Comment: you are also using deprecated functions.  don't use `mysql_`, use mysqli or PDO

Comment: and md5 is  no longer considered secure

Comment: what don't you use `password_*` functions ? (if you're PHP 5.5+ or 5.3 with compatibility pack)

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of WTF's there.

**1) As said in comments, SQL Injection is a major worry.**
You're using `htmlentities` to escape `$email` but that function is only good to prevent you from injecting html into the site. As for preventing something from messing up with your DB? Not so much. It doesn't escape `'`. It assumes `ISO-8859`, etc... you should always use `htmlentities` when writing content to the user. Not when getting content from the user. Take a look into **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)** to escape SQL properly.

**2) After validating the user you're sending the md5'ed password back and forth as a cookie.**
Why? Makes no sense really. Non salted MD5 is easlly decrypted using one of the many rainbow tables out there. Just see [how easy it is to crack](http://md5cracker.org/) a non-salted password. And this isn't a good enough session key. If you want to take sessions out of the server and the database for massive scalling see what Laravel/php, Play Framework/java and others are doing inspired on RoR/ruby - encrypted cookies.

3) **While the PBKDF2 is perfectly alright you probably should go with [php's password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)**.
It's simpler, deals with salt for you in a completelly transparent way, makes way for updates both in encryption algo and in hash time cost and comes bundled in a nice API.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your answer, maybe you could rename "crypt" to "password_hash" to avoid confusions? The crypt function itself does not handle the salt and can easily be used wrong.

Comment: Yes but i dont see why i cant get a same hash from db for that user because hash always chaning? I give a full code up

Comment: @goeiu3eu - The hash will be different, because a random salt is generated for each hash. To verify the password you cannot search with an SQL query, you will first have to retrieve the hash from the database by username, then you can extract the salt from the hash, and afterwards you can use the same salt for the verification.